# Set-up for the Paris-Harrington Theorem

Tags: logic, model-theory, peano-axioms, nonstandard-models

In his book "Models of Peano Arithmetic" Kaye proves the Paris-Harrington Theorem. He starts off by introducing a "simplification" then proves the short Lemma 14.11 about it (see picture). I don't understand any of this. Specifically:

1. What is the rational of the "Truth definition for $I$" (just above Lemma 14.11 in the picture)?
2. Why does "$I \subset_e M$ is a structure of the language $\mathcal{L}_A$ of arithmetic" imply that $I \models \text{PA}^{-}$?
3. I don't understand at all why the proof shows that $I \models \text{PA}$. Why does the proof imply that $I$ models all induction axioms?

Basically, can someone explain the proof and its background, because I'm completely lost. I would greatly appreciate any help!

[image: Set-up of Paris-Harrington Theorem proof]

Comment: Much of the background for these questions is provided in earlier sections of this book. Are you familiar with them? For example, your question (2) is stated as exercise 2.11, and so you might want to look through that section. Background on truth definitions is in chapter 9, though that's very technical as well.

Comment: @AtharAbdul-Quader Salaam 3laykum, thanks for your comment! I massively appreciate all the help I can get! Especially from someone that does PA model theory as their PhD! I'll look at exercise 2.11; I added that questions as an afterthought. My main issue is with (3) and also with (1), although I am willing to take the definitions on faith. I've actually read chapter 9 completely and in detail, as well as most of the material before this chapter (although not everything), but it doesn't really help me here. The whole chapter on indicators lacks motivation for me.

Comment: After chapter 9 I find some proofs and intuition increasing unclear, especially in chapter 14 on indicators, but also earlier the proof of MacDowell-Specker. However, the book starts off pretty lucidly, and even chapter 9 was still somewhat clear (at least what the goal is), but then at some point I slowly lost the big picture, and now I feel completely lost in chapter 14.

Comment: Wa alaikum salaam. For (3), the main idea is to show that the least number principle holds in I. This is equivalent to induction.

Comment: For (1), I'm not sure what your question is. Are you asking why it's necessary to have a truth definition for I for the lemma? Or are you asking how we know such a truth definition exists, or something else?

Comment: @AtharAbdul-Quader Oh yes, using LNP makes a lot of sense. When I'm confused about the motivation I also start missing simple things :)! For (1), what I'm trying to understand is where the definition comes from? And why is it reasonable to expect that there should be such a truth definition and that it is useful? Why would someone suddenly start to look at coded initial segments and how come this entails a useful truth condition for initial segments? I know these are broad questions, but some indication about how to think of the material would already be hugely beneficial for me.

Comment: I'm reading Kaye's book for a reading project, but unfortunately there are no teachers at my university that can properly supervise it, so I'm pretty much on my own with any questions. Jazaak Allahu khairan.

Comment: @AtharAbdul-Quader I've just reread the proof and your brief comments completely elucidate it. Save for (1) I'm sure I understand what's going on, and it's much less mysterious than I thought. This shows that a few guiding words can make a lot of impact. However, I'm now stuck a theorem down, and although I'm sure it's probably a minor issue, I really need some short guidance again. But these questions are really a bit too minor and specialized to be useful here. I'm sure you're very busy, but is it possible that I email you these brief questions? I just need to understand Paris-Harrington :).

Answer (score 1):

Re: (2), first remember that all but one of the axioms of $\mathsf{PA^-}$ are universal, hence downwards-absolute between structures: since $I$ is a substructure of a model of $\mathsf{PA^-}$ it satisfies all of these sentences too.

So this just leaves the thirteenth axiom: $$\mathsf{Ax13}:\quad\forall x,y(x<y\rightarrow \exists z(x+z=y)).$$

This is where we use the fact that $I\subset_eM$, or more intuitively that $I$ is **downwards closed**. Let $x,y\in I$ with $x<y$. Applying $\mathsf{Ax13}$ in $M$ we get in $M$ some $z$ such that $x+z=y$. In $M$ we have $z\le y$; since $I$ is downwards closed this means $z\in M$. Now the property $x+z=y$ is absolute between $I$ and $M$, so $I\models x+z=y$. And this gives $\mathsf{Ax13}$ in $I$ as desired.

Note that we needed end extension as opposed to mere superstructurehood, in verifying axiom $13$. It's a good exercise to check that every nonstandard model of $\mathsf{PA}$ has a (necessarily non-downwards-closed) substructure not satisfying axiom $13$. On the other hand, if we included "symmetric subtraction" $(x,y)\mapsto \vert x-y\vert$ as a primitive operation, then $\mathsf{Ax13}$ can be rephrased as a universal and after such rephrasing every substructure of a model of $\mathsf{PA^-}$ would again satisfy $\mathsf{PA}^-$.

Comment: Thanks Noah. I've edited your answer; can you check whether my edit is correct? If so, I'm positive I understand your answer.

Comment: @Jori Yup - good catch, that was a bad typo on my part!